# Path variations in deriving Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mathematics, variational-principle, variational-calculus

This is a basic question about Euler-Lagrange equations that I could not find being addressed anywhere else (some similar questions: [Q1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/516027/variation-of-path-in-the-derivation-of-the-euler-lagrange-equation) and [Q2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/545177/question-about-small-variation-in-path-in-derivation-of-euler-lagrange-equation)).

In deriving the Euler-Lagrange equations from the functional
$$ S = \int_{x_a}^{x_b} f(y,y',x)  \, dx $$
one takes the first variation of $S$ through varying the optimal path $y_c$ according to $y(x)=y_c(x) + \epsilon \eta(x)$ where $\eta$ is assumed to be an arbitrary function (with $\eta(x_a) = \eta(x_b) = 0$). One obtains
$$\delta S = \epsilon \int_{x_a}^{x_b} \eta \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg\rvert_{y_c} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\bigg\rvert_{y_c}\right) \, dx$$
which should vanish for arbitrary $\eta$ and from which Euler-Lagrange equation results.

**First Question** is about the arbitrariness of $\eta$; intuitively, I'd think $\eta$ should be 'perpendicular' to $y_c$ at each point, or otherwise $y_c + \epsilon \eta$ would not define a new path. Is this intuitive picture wrong?

I guess this is probably more relevant for the multidimensional case. For example, consider $f = f( \lbrace y_i \rbrace_{i=1}^n,x)$ where $f$ does not depend on $y'_i$; then following along the same steps, one arrives at
$$ \delta S = \epsilon \int_{x_a}^{x_b} dx \, \sum_{i=1}^n \, \eta_i \, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i} \bigg\rvert_{y_c} = \epsilon \int_{x_a}^{x_b} dx \, \mathbf{\eta}\cdot\nabla f =0 .$$
This can either mean that $\nabla f(\mathbf{y}_c)=0$ at each point; alternatively if we are only considering $\eta$'s that are perpendicular to the optimising path, this means that the optimal path should be along the gradient of $f$ at each point. Are either of these two the correct conclusion here?

**Second Question**
Regardless of the question about the nature of $\eta$, such a path that connects $x_a$ to $x_b$ and satisfies either of these conditions (ie $\nabla f=0$ or being along $\nabla f$) may not exist after all -- this seems to me to be the case especially when $f = f(y,x)$ is independent of $y'$; how can one find the optimizing $y$ then?

Comment: Why would it not define a new path? $\eta$ just has to vanish at the end points so that $y_c+\epsilon\eta$ is a path with same endpoints as $y_c$. Other than the requirement that $\eta$ vanish at endpoints (and having sufficient smoothness) it can be an arbitrary function.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see, I guess you are right. For example one could go back and forth on some pieces of the same path and that is a new one. What do you think about the last question?

Comment: If an integral vanishes for all choices of $\eta$ then the integrand has to vanish. There's never a need to show the existence of a specific $\eta$ so I'm not sure what more I can say

Comment: @peek-a-boo To be more clear, I mean if $\eta$ is arbitrary, then for $f$ that does not depend on $y'$ we should have $\nabla f=0$ and there may be no $y(x)$ that goes from $x_a$ to $x_b$ and satisfies this condition. Then what can be done to find $y$ (and not $\eta$) that minimizes $S$?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following helps you but anyways. In ordinary multidimensional calculus if one has a differentiable, scalar function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, one can define the directional derivative as
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\vec{n}}f(\vec{x}) := \frac{d}{d\varepsilon}f(\vec{x}+ \epsilon \vec{n})\Big |_{\varepsilon = 0} = \nabla f \cdot \vec{n}
\end{equation}
for some unit vector $\vec{n}\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Now the functional is again just a scalar function $S: V \to \mathbb{R}$, just this time, $V$ is usually a infinite dimensional vector space, for example $C^{\infty}$. The paths $y : [x_a,x_b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are then the "input vectors" from $C^\infty$ and the variation $\delta S$ is really with respect to a "direction" $\eta \in C^\infty$ within this function space $C^\infty$. With this, analogous to the equation above
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}F(y+ \epsilon \eta)\Big|_{\varepsilon=0} = \int_{x_a}^{x_b} \frac{\delta F[y]}{\delta y} \eta(x) dx = \langle \frac{\delta F[y]}{\delta y},  \eta(x) \rangle
\end{equation}
One can recognise the integral, as suggested by the notation as a scalar product in the infinite dimensional vector space. And if this integral vanishes (i.e. $\delta S=0$ for all variations), the "functional-derivative" $\frac{\delta F[y]}{\delta y}$ must vanish, since it is $orthogonal$ to every vector $\eta$, in the sense of vanishing scalar product. So yes, $\eta$ is perpendicular to $\frac{\delta F[y]}{\delta y}$, but the only vector that is perpendicular to every other vector is then recognised to be the $0$ vector. Thus $\frac{\delta F[y]}{\delta y}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}- \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}=0$

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice way of looking at it. I have edited the post to reflect the two separate questions that I have, so any clue on the second question would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the Euler-Lagrange equation itself provides the answer to your question.

The process of deriving the Euler-Lagrange equation is a process of boiling down to the essence. The Euler-Lagrange equation specifies a particular differentiation. That specific differentiation is the core.

Example:
Application of the Euler-Lagrange equation in Classical Mechanics:

In theory of motion:
The Euler-Lagrange equation is populated with expressions for energy. Those expressions for energy are obtained with the [Work-Energy theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/696623/17198)

Recapitulating:
Potential energy is a function of position; the value of the potential energy is obtained by integrating force with respect to the position coordinate. Kinetic energy is the integral of $ma$ (mass times acceleration) with respect to the position coordinate.

In theory of motion:
The Euler-Lagrange equation (populated with potential energy and kinetic energy) takes the derivative of the energy with respect to the position coordinate.

The next step is to take this result and use it to inform you about what the variation is. Whatever arbitrariness is *attributed* in the early stage: in the end the aspect of the variation that makes it to the Euler-Lagrange equation is variation of position coordinate.

(Conversely, everything that does *not* make it to the Euler-Lagrange euqation is manifestly superfluous.)

**Linear independence**

You used the expression 'perpendicular', I take it that you are referring to the property of *linear independence*. The direction of integration of the functional, and the direction of the variation, are independent.

Example:
Plot motion as a function of time using cartesian coordinates.
When you sweep out variation: that is variation of the position coordinate. The direction of the variation sweep is perpendicular to the time axis.

Further reading:
There is an oktober 2021 discussion by me of [Hamilton's stationary action](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/670705/17198). That discussion is illustrated with diagrams.

The derivative of kinetic energy with respect to the position coordinate:

$$ \frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2)}{ds} = \tfrac{1}{2}m\left( 2v\frac{dv}{ds} \right) = m\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{dv}{ds} = m\frac{dv}{dt} = ma \tag{1} $$

The Euler-Lagrange does a chained differentiation; first differentiation with respect to velocity 'v', and then differentiation with respect to time 't'.

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2)}{dv} = \frac{d}{dt}mv = ma \tag{2} $$

Both (1) and (2) evaluate to $ma$, so in effect (1) and (2) are the same differentiation, only the order of operations is different.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand the answer to my Q1 by combining peek-a-boo comments and your answer; do you have anything to add for Q2?

Comment: @SaMaSo I can only repeat: absorb the discussion of [application of Calculus of Variations in physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/670705/17198), submitted by me in oktober 2021. That discussion goes to the core. (Well, I believe it does.) My contribution is to offer the opportunity to understand. Naturally my hope is that you will take the opportunity.